# Simple relation of Dirac matrices in Dirac propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, propagator, dirac-matrices

There is this equivalence between representations for the Dirac propagator: $$\frac{i}{\not{p}-m}=\frac{i(\not p+m)}{p^2-m^2}.$$ The only way i could think this to be true is if $\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}p_{\nu}=p^2.$ What property guarantees this?

I know i'm missing something pretty easy here. Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep.

$$\gamma^\mu p_\mu \gamma^\nu p_\nu=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu p_\mu p_\nu=\tfrac{1}{2}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu p_\mu p_\nu +\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu p_\nu p_\mu)=\tfrac{1}{2}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu p_\mu p_\nu +\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu p_\mu p_\nu)=\tfrac{1}{2}\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}p_{\mu}p_\nu$$

Assuming your Gammas have $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}$, you're done.

Comment: Off couse...Thanks!

Comment: @user21299 After the last step - $\frac{1}{2}\big\{ \gamma ^{\mu} , \gamma ^{\nu} \big\} p_{\mu} p_{\nu} = g^{\mu \nu}I_4 p_{\mu}p_{\nu} = \big(p^{\nu}p_{\nu}\big)I_4 = \big(p_0 ^2 - \overrightarrow{p}^2 \big)I_4 $ which is not $= p^2$. Could you point to what I am missing? Thanks.