# Inverse of Dirac Propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, field-theory, dirac-equation, propagator

Note -  This question is slightly different from a similar question already posted [here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/595305/simple-relation-of-dirac-matrices-in-dirac-propagator) 
While self-learning field theory, I'm stuck at how to prove the following -

$\frac{1}{\not{p}-m} = \frac{\not{p}+m}{p^2 - m^2}$

My attempt - 
$\frac{1}{\not{p}-m}=\frac{\not{p}+m}{\big(\not{p}+m\big)\big(\not{p}-m\big)}= \frac{\not{p}+m}{\not{p}\not{p}-m^2}$ 
 Now, $\not{p}\not{p}=\gamma^\mu p_\mu \gamma^\nu p_\nu=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu p_\mu p_\nu=\tfrac{1}{2}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu p_\mu p_\nu +\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu p_\nu p_\mu)=\tfrac{1}{2}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu p_\mu p_\nu +\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu p_\mu p_\nu)=\frac{1}{2}\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}p_{\mu}p_\nu = \frac{1}{2}\big\{ \gamma ^{\mu} , \gamma ^{\nu} \big\} p_{\mu} p_{\nu} = g^{\mu \nu}I_4 p_{\mu}p_{\nu} = \big(p^{\nu}p_{\nu}\big)I_4 = \big(p_0 ^2 - \overrightarrow{p}^2 \big)I_4 $ which is not $= p^2$ (the first term in the denominator on the right-hand side of the above relation). 
 Could someone point towards what I am missing?

Comment: Are you just confused about the $I_4$?

Comment: @KilianM I'm confused about - 1) $I_4$  2) How is $p_0 ^2 - \overrightarrow{p}^2$ (as it comes out in my calculation in the last step)$ = p^2$ (actually given in the relation)? Thanks.

Comment: Remember that the m also has an identity matrix attached to it, it's just often not written as it is understood.

Comment: @user263315 In particle physics one often takes $g_{\mu\nu}$ the Minkowski metric i.e. $g_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(1,-1,-1-,1)$. Some authors use $\eta_{\mu\nu}$. This means $p^2=p^\mu g_{\mu\nu} p^\nu=p_0^2-\vec{p}^2$. Is that what you mean by 2)?

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion yes, that's exactly what my problem was - I wasn't able to understand if $p^2=p^\mu g_{\mu\nu} p^\nu $ was really $=p_0^2-\vec{p}^2$. If they are (equal), then my main problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: @Triatticus okay, that solves my issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Triatticus But then that means the denominator- $\big(p^2 - m \big)I_4$ is NOT a scalar object but a matrix in Dirac space?

Comment: Consider that the original object was already a matrix in the denominator.

Comment: @Triatticus Yes, I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the expression $\frac{1}{\not{p}-m}$ is actually abuse of notation for $({\not{p}-m})^{-1}$ i.e. the matrix inverse of $\not p-m$. What you showed is that $({\not{p}-m})^{-1}=\big[(p^2-m^2) _4\big]^{-1}(\not p+m)=\frac{1}{p^2-m^2}(\not p+m)$ so you are free to leave out the $_4$ in your final expression.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion yes, that certainly makes sense. Thanks.